# how to get an auto generated id from firestore database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created a database in firestore db to store the comments of users in a post. The database generates the comment id automatically when ever comment is added. Now i wanted to delete a comment using its id to avoid deleting others alongside it. How can i get a comment auto generated id to delete it from the database ?

This is my code for adding  Comments in the db.

```
addComments() {
    commentsRef.document(postId).collection('comments').add({
      'username': currentUser.username,
      'comment': commentController.text,
      'avatar': currentUser.photoUrl,
      'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
      'userId': currentUser.id,
      'likes': {},
    });
    bool isNotPostOwner = postOwnerId != currentUser.id;
    if (isNotPostOwner) {
      activityFeedRef.document(postOwnerId).collection('feedItems').add({
        'type': 'comment',
        'commentData': commentController.text,
        'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
        'postId': postId,
        'ownerId': currentUser.id,
        'username': currentUser.username,
        'userProfileImg': currentUser.photoUrl,
        'mediaUrl': postMediaUrl,
      });
    }
    commentController.clear();
  }
```

I tried using this code to delete it but it deletes all the data in the comment collection

```
  deleteComment() async {
    QuerySnapshot commentsSnapshot = await commentsRef
        .document(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .getDocuments();
    commentsSnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        doc.reference.delete();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> The database generates the comment id automatically

Actually, that's not really true.  The client SDK generates the random ID locally, and it's virtually guaranteed not to collide with any other ID that could exist.

If your client app needs to work with the document later, it will either have to:

1. Remember the ID for later use.
2. Query Firestore to find the document, using information in the fields to locate it.

These are your only two options.

If you want to get the ID of the document after the call to add(), note that [add()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) returns a Future that resolves with DocumentReference for the new document.  That [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) has a [documentID](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/documentID.html) property.

Answer (score 0):

you can get document id when it's generated.

```
db.collection('students').add({'name': 'John'})
.then((val)=> print(val.documentID)});
```

Comment: How can I use the document to delete the data.. That is what I wanted to know.

Comment: Your question is not clear. First you asked how to get the document id after it is generated.

Comment: Yes when I get the document id then i will use it to delete it to avoid deleting others

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: No like if I wanted to delete it.. Like fb does.

Comment: Your whole structure is wrong. You got the id now do with it anything you want.

Comment: Ok let me try it out